# TensorFlowについて

Tags: python, tensorflow

PythonのprintとTensorflowのチュートリアルについて

Tensor flowのチュートリアルの一番初めのMNISTをやっています。
その中でx,yや重みやバイアスであるb,Wの中身を見てみたいです。

そのために

```
>>>print x,y,b,W
```

を実行しても

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(784)]), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(10)]), dtype=float32)
<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x1006b0b90>
<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x101b76410>
```

と表示されます。
重みやバイアスには実際の値が入ってますよね？
それらを表示させる方法はないですか？

教えてください、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

tensorflowの変数は， いわゆる変数ではなく`tensorflow`のセッション中の操作を指し示すものです． まず`x`は`sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})`のようにtensorflowのセッションにわたされた入力(この場合`batch_xs`)が代入される変数を表わしているので，セッッション外では値はありません．また`y`は`x`，`W`，`b`にたいする操作なので値はきまりません．`b`と`W`セッション内で`b`や`W`の値をわたす操作を表わしているため，セッションにこの操作を評価させれば以下のように表示できます．

```
print sess.run(W)
print sess.run(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

ipythonなどの対話型シェルでは、tf.InteractiveSessionを使うと良いです。

[tensorflowのドキュメント](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession])にある例を手元で実行した結果が以下です。

```py
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [3]: a = tf.constant(5.0)

In [4]: b = tf.constant(6.0)

In [5]: c = a * b

In [6]: print(c.eval())
30.0

In [7]: sess.close()
```

a.eval()やb.eval()としても変数の値を見ることが出来ます。